# Get a more useful value than "[object Object]" for debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging, object-to-string

Couldn't there a be a environment flag in JavaScript so you could turn on some metadata for objects.

So instead when you are debugging and get:

```
[object Object]
```

you would get the variable name and type:

```
[foo String]
```

why isn't this possible?

Comment: How are you debugging though? I think that's the key question.

Comment: Javascript is not strongly typed (or it can be argued typed at all)

Comment: You could define a your own function which shows the "typeof x" when you are for example using "console.log". So try writing console.log(typeof yourVariable).

Comment: the `toString()` representation will look like that, but `console.log`'s result will be more verbose. FF has `Object.prototype.toSource()` which is also good. What debugger are you using?

Comment: `console.log` will vary by platform; in some it will still [ToString]. `console.dir` is a bit more "portable", or at least consistent where it is supported. Best way to debug though is with an attached debugger .. and unit tests .. instead of embedding such "debug code" into the program itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you extract content out of object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249367/how-do-you-extract-content-out-of-object)

Comment: You're clearly not using the console of a modern browser, which is what you should be doing. Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` might be what you are looking for, though it won't give you the name of the variable – JavaScript simply can't do that without 3rd party tools.

The constructor function of your object can be reached by using its `constructor` property, though there's no guarantee with this as the constructor property is writable.

You might also want to look into the [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement.

Comment: right, but there could be a way to start the JavaScript runtime with a flag set to turn on that metadata. Basically, it would slow down the execution, but would give you debugging metadata.

Comment: @AlexMills As far as I know there is nothing of that sort in any JavaScript standard, and none of the big browsers implement such a thing. I've edited my answer with another possible suggestion.

Comment: @AlexMills Of course if your target platform is not a browser then it might be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky , but it can help you to find what is your object source :

```
function Foo()
{}

var toClass = function(a)
{
    var _name = a.constructor.toString().match(/^function (\w+)/i); //\w probably should be enhanced
    console.log(_name[1])
}

toClass( new Foo()) //Foo
toClass( [1, 2]) //Array
toClass( new Date()) //Date
toClass( {"a":2}) //Object
```

Aside note : *don't* override `toString` just for debugging. `toString` has its purpose. and should be used as it was meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question about just flipping a "global flag" instead of changing your debugging methodology:

Assuming you'd only do this during debugging, you can temporarily override the `Object.prototype.toString` to return a JSON representation of objects:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function () { return JSON.stringify(this); };
```

Then in the browser console:

```
var obj = { a: 42 };
console.log('My object: ' + obj);
```

Will give you:

```
My object: {"a":42}
```

Even if this answers your question, I don't recommend a global override of a base method because it has the potential to cause catastrophic issues. Try relying on unit tests and breakpoints + debugging as others have suggested in comments.

Comment: @Acidic Yes, and I've explicitly stated that in my response. I hope you fully read my answer. The purpose of it was educational. I don't like to idea of holding back information about a method just because it is bad practice.

Comment: Then why even post this in the first place? This is a really bad idea no matter how you look at it, and I don't see how an answer that shows inherently bad code is "educating".

Comment: @Acidic You really believe education is only about showing what's good?

Comment: I don't, but in my opinion your answer does not clearly present the code as an example of how not to do something. This could be a contributing piece of information under the title of *what to avoid*.